# Is it possible to display embedded mp4 subtitles in an HMTL5 <video> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, video, web, html5-video

So far I've found that this isn't possible.  For the purpose of simplifying my media library, I'm developing a locally-run site that takes media files (MP4 containing H.264 codec) and displays them in a `<video>` tag.

However, some of this media is in languages other than English, and contain embedded subtitles within the file.  As there are hundreds of files, I'd like to not have to go through and extract each of the subtitle tracks file by file.

Is there a way (a JS library, or a feature in HTML5) that allows embedded subtitles to be displayed in a `<track>` tag?

Comment: If you mean hardcoded subtitles, then it isn't possible. When a hardcoded subtitle appears it is because it is actually part of the video frame just as the image of the frame is. So an average video of over a thousand frames would have a little under a thousand or so frames with permanently embedded subtitles. There is software that removes watermarks so there might be one that removes hardcoded subtitles but I'm sure the quality isn't great.

Comment: @zer00ne I think Asker means [**subtitles in MP4 metadata**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap3/qtff3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH205-SW81). Which is not possible since it's a different data format to the `<video>` tag's expected VTT or SRT type data. Only thing is to process the metadata and analyse the subtitle bytes to re-create as VTT style formatting (in a temp `String` variable?) that is now fed as input to `<track>` tag. Or else use a tool to extract/convert from input video before uploading both files.

Comment: @VC.One, thank you, that is indeed what I meant.  Usually the media comes with more than one language selectable within media players as well.  I'll do some research and see if there is a way to read the MP4's metadata with JS.

Comment: not really an answer, but have you looked at something like Plex as an alternative to rolling your own? also you can use ffmpeg to extract the subtitles to a vtt file http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#Subtitle-Formats